# How to loop reading files group by group?

Tags: python

Generally, I loop through files one by one in Python. Now I want to loop through them group by group. How do I read them efficiently?

Here's an example to explain my question.

Given files like these:

```
group1: m2000_01, m2000_02，..., m2000_12
group2: m2001_01, m2001_02,...., m2001_12
 .....
group17: m2016_01, m2016_02,...., m2016_12
```

I want to read files in same year for calculation and loop alone time serials for batching. Pseudo-code as follow:

```
for year in list[2000,2001,...,2016]:

   A=open(m2000_01), B=open(m2000_02), C=open(m2000_03)....   # reading files section

   mean2000 = (A + B + C ...) / 12
    #calculation body,how to set varibles for each file.such as A=m2000_01, B=m2000_02, ...,
    #use a dict to set these files?

print mean2000, mean2001,..., mean2016    #result I want
```

Maybe I could make a list, and then loop element in list for matching(seive) and extracting group files. But if there are many groups of files and the group key words (such as `2000` in above example) are irregular. Are there any common method to solve similar problems? I think there is a proven method, but I don't know how to describe and search. Please forgive me if this problem is simple.

Comment: Have you looked at the glob module?

Comment: I always use os.walk and os.list traverse files instead of glob module. I'm looking the usage of glob module.@MKesper

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```
import os

path = "your\\path"

all_files = [x for x in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(path + "\\" + x)]

for year in range(2000, 2017):
    for file_name in [y for y in all_files if str(year) in y]:
        sub_file_path = path + "\\" + file_name
        # read file, insert appropriate code yourself
```

Comment: Maybe use os.path instead of manually joining paths? We don't know the os of OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can find and group the files for processing using `os.listdir()`, along with the `re` regex module, and the `itertools.groupby()` function to do something along these lines:

```
from itertools import groupby
import os
import re

folder_path = 'data_folder'

pattern = r'm\d\d\d\d_\d\d'
filenames = [filename for filename in sorted(os.listdir(folder_path)) 
                if re.match(pattern, filename)]

for k, g in groupby(filenames, lambda filename: filename.split('_')[0]):
    year = int(k[1:])
    year_files = list(g)
    print('{}: {}'.format(year, year_files))
```

Sample output:

```
2000: ['m2000_01', 'm2000_02', 'm2000_03', 'm2000_04', 'm2000_05', 'm2000_06', 'm2000_07', 'm2000_08', 'm2000_09', 'm2000_10', 'm2000_11', 'm2000_12']
2001: ['m2001_01', 'm2001_02', 'm2001_03', 'm2001_04', 'm2001_05', 'm2001_06', 'm2001_07', 'm2001_08', 'm2001_09', 'm2001_10', 'm2001_11', 'm2001_12']
2002: ['m2002_01', 'm2002_02', 'm2002_03', 'm2002_04', 'm2002_05', 'm2002_06', 'm2002_07', 'm2002_08', 'm2002_09', 'm2002_10', 'm2002_11', 'm2002_12']
```

Comment: I'm never sure what is more readable with regexes, as you have it, or something like: `r'm\d{4}_\d{2}`

Comment: @Baldrickk: At less than 5 replications, I usually just spell it out—it's about the same amount of typing and equally readable IMO, with 4 being a bit of an edge case...